# How to split StoryBoard and Code for UITableViewCells in Xcode 13?

Tags: swift, xcode13

How can I split Xcode view as Storyboard and code? ViewControllers are ok just by pressing ctrl + option + command + enter. But it doesn't work for Tableview cells. The code still showing to VC class instead of Cell class. Any Help?

Comment: Try selecting the cell’s content view first

Comment: I got it. There's a section called "Automatic" in top to choose between swift files.